# Command line arguments reading for flags and file names in C

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments, word-count

Hello I have a project I'm doing and I need my program to run from the command line and be able to read flags and file names that will be used in the program.

This is my current code. It compiles without entering any flags. I don't think my GetArgs does anything. I had help with that part of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 1024
#define IN 1 /* inside a word */ 
#define OUT 0 /* outside a word */
/* count lines, words, and characters in input */

int numInputArgs;
int idx;
void GetArgs (int argc, char **argv){

for (idx = 1; idx < 4;  idx++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[idx], "-c") == 0) {
        printf("Flag -c passed\n");
        break;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[idx], "-w") == 0) {
        printf("Flag -w passed\n");
        break;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[idx], "-l") == 0) {
        printf("Flag -l passed\n");
        break;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[idx], "-L") == 0) {
        printf("Flag -L passed\n");
        break;
    }
    else {
        printf("Error: unknown flag\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
 }// end GetArgs

void lineWordCount ( ) {

int c, nl, nw, nc, state;


    state = OUT; nl = nw = nc = 0; 
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            ++nc;

        if (c == '\n')
            ++nl; 

        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT; 

        else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN; ++nw;
        } 
        printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
    }
 }// end lineWordCount








 int main(int argc, char **argv){

GetArgs(argc, argv);
lineWordCount();
printf("Hello");

//fclose( src );
}
```

Comment: FYI: homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: You're right, all `GetArgs` does is print the arguments. If you are on a POSIX machine (like Linux or Mac OSX) I suggest you look to [`getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getopt.html). There are also many arguments parsing libraries available if you search, the above mentioned `getopt` function exists for Windows as well for example.

Comment: Your GetArgs does perfectly what it should:

`$ gcc -o issue issue.c`

`$ ./issue.exe a b c`

*abc*

So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I need the GetArgs to be able to scan for four potentially flags that decide what information is displayed at the end. before processing the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use a standard function like `getopt()` as mentioned by @Joachim, if it is available on your system, or you can code it yourself. If you have a complicated command line syntax, `getopt()` might be better suited - if you only need to check for a limited set of flags, it might be easier to code it yourself, for example:

```
void GetArgs (int argc, char **argv){
   int idx = 0;

   for (idx = 1; idx < argc;  idx++) {
       if (strcmp(argv[idx], "-a") == 0) {
          printf("Flag -a passed\n");
       } else if (strcmp(argv[idx], "-b") == 0) {
          printf("Flag -b passed\n");
       } else if (strcmp(argv[idx], "-c") == 0) {
          printf("Flag -c passed\n");
       } else {
          printf("Error: unknown flag %s\n");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with my main.. It isn't printing anything else besides what's in lineWordCount

Comment: lineWordCount() is not called at all in your code above. I took your code and passed it to the compiler unmodified, and when I call the programm with several command line arguments it prints each of them, exactly what I would expect ...

Comment: I added it right under GetArgs in main and I'm getting stuck in the GetArgs. Trying to mess with it so it will get to lineWordCount. I'll update the code right now.

Comment: Your program works quite well, the only issue is in the for() loop: you expect a fixed number of 4 arguments in `idx < 4`, you need to code it as `idx < argc`. Then, call it like `issue.exe < issue.c` and it prints everything. Note that you are reading from `stdin` with `getchar()`, so you need to pass something to stdin on the command line.

Comment: Yeah I changed that code back to ' idc < argc ' but my program never finishes for me. I have the lineWordCount following the GetArgs in main but it just never finished the program

Comment: I figured out why. I was using UNIX built in "wc" (word count) and I thought it was my program functioning. :(

Comment: In the unix shell, always call your program with `./` prepended to avoid such issues. Also, avoid using existing names (you can check with `which` or `where`)

Comment: Yeah. Found out the hard way. Thank you Andreas for all your help and kindness. The assignment is due shortly and I have no idea how to make this spit out anything remotely close.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [argtable2](http://argtable.sourceforge.net/) library. I have used it for a long time and I think it is great. There are tutorials available to see how powerful and easy to use it is.